# Json parsing to get lat long

Tags: android, json

I have a response from a google web service like the follwing

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CpQCBgEAALxtLOBsfDviXsb8WHg4nGHrCETBydo0YcgOw-IHvFS4CQI1ZaM331dtA8Y3CxPeZZlF0IYjwQMp2A8W5A5UKtTrR4sQq1Um6FJgUNCpZzrcT6RwaPJKzOjbaFrPt5GqnQM6W1vxxdK9nKu5lyBbvLr0yJnzBWEAqyLyT2MFvak-_qDIR8b3yK3Efy34SsoHNnBnaANVc5hMztz7aWGphkTDNtEfuSZnQQ72jPg5_ey5F2G29in_QJXJlR9a3YYNGFmefLta2e0T34OGOhtvCinrdE7dcEUuaK55LV8TnP33HlGKC7PruXkv4AF8Xvxnlsk9ALVFdzECmJ4br6RTq3iWjBZ0z5FPNzqjfa6NNFiqEhDItZbJiBr9cEOaefilqJQSGhSybiB6SRFA8b-p86rFbiNEHjEo3w",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.610399,
               "lng" : -122.335791
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "8f7e7d038dbd13f283d1875ecf68d04fc2255561",
         "name" : "GNC",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ3zJ_hLRqkFQR0AxDtprgAjI",
         "price_level" : 2,
         "reference" : "CnRlAAAAoWRGwTPL4nLYI7qPZ2ukmXEdDWAScl5XASmeogPbQsOEvbFdXvb2cMYWsQZ1LR3QUYDo8djSpfKQc0BFLkA37iw_iTW2XRZy4568H5kReNd1xqVDjZyVmHPaWnKkJrTl0bJh_1P1Vpg-ntqUq-zVkRIQDVbTyrun8WsRA1eftayO8RoUSwjCBqkVaPwmyLJtXfJfk9qmF2I",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "health", "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "421 Pike St, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.61,
               "lng" : -122.33
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "82e45a03dca8dcb2192cc250777a11f2e06452de",
         "name" : "Deluxe Foods LLC",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ9dKBxbVqkFQRoDLJeSe0CZo",
         "reference" : "CoQBcwAAAD1dI5pifx1zH03cyQyPsJL10GZc7UFMHEKgZVzmIbZ77ZUdoXAme2iE3WzBgcCUuwg3zv735Pey9MrLWXdbKBmBGl_mvs_dD6aMmNYEhwft54gVpabn0ZVNLrflNEyun-dUkoeHvx5GEWNj1UvYGB1zbCY1CSUwbiqH4Ouay9GpEhBHwGUT7yCYw9IC3hGGUUxgGhRHU_AjT-jsRrHxoC6o7YKVpCLyCg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "PO Box 30102, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.607573,
               "lng" : -122.333167
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "695bf0d73be3b5f55ca43fe14abce48f9853ef15",
         "name" : "Community Grocery",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJNeh4UrFqkFQRV3OXAHsHZxg",
         "reference" : "CoQBcwAAALpG-2YSWEiceu-5h5km-SYuQelZR70nMSMg9uhs38uPusDF4s_5hnf6eQ8ORGJf7JGv9w9il4cL9to8r0bcA7HxK2ghxkrWlBbcP2asPWJTCdzrQB-uUs9TKxHc-kldayis9zmLQtHoDW_J8sSXlZHnHNYPol9VjKZIUiIlpYTNEhD9a-VcIRldCMVZhHNow03fGhRsw5lDMDZOcVEHdRBz2NAuhTdZ3Q",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "415 Seneca St, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.608163,
               "lng" : -122.335371
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/wine-71.png",
         "id" : "fde562e2d1e74e8ea18d3f758a05fe78c45d9346",
         "name" : "Essential Market",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJvYQm8LNqkFQRjJM6WIcYE1A",
         "rating" : 3.8,
         "reference" : "CoQBcgAAALd33oAy_-Vxbcbf_gMywCqPHjyZixFi-yc1glcFFxbtpTDywxT-vPFKNExST7K305Ohv0AkhA_Br2Eh8AeetN-D7PxuW3mK5vsYPUbIfOTRWoM_CX2YH84cXOj9eFwGXwTiuXEOvOjhz8SYj59N4g78IUUDi-mfmGzd_C_jq90REhDJ3y45nfvr6IbfvapMnK0ZGhQDCjyU7Zu8ymTuQLGmoEsJRTVVGQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "liquor_store",
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "1301 4th Ave, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.612122,
               "lng" : -122.332044
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "6b4f8dc7039510bbbfca8fd12b359d444eef2be9",
         "name" : "Clay's Market",
         "place_id" : "ChIJdxjOE7VqkFQR4oDXOXnQEQ8",
         "reference" : "CnRvAAAACC-kzX3pJo0x3OjptaM_wqWs5kbrk53V4xa6gYiOj3PP8Fo8L_DqSTjKRMqrF8bRGVfnTKtaLujZLvxkIgj7pNjyTAauRPKv0TL7dHpru66CyaJRNjoRSHME0xYHJJNj7VQDeLl5HO8dab0FZFrevxIQ6tZzbeqqRp6QEPf_Ue7XhBoU4Y3VkFBSCx_4b1pu1ApLYwXzLDQ",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "815 Pike St, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.609336,
               "lng" : -122.337791
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "691548827b64fe2609fb7c27abbb1bcbe224f327",
         "name" : "Kress IGA Supermarket",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 600,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAl-_QCXEqC8UaTUMrQDzG_bDcP56Lf2i2CPbBmxYj71VlemLiDrQpC38wmDTwsHvoFF_pGjLBo4vQHfPjM2nSLrPmHQeotYySYTwBhOcXPF9ISdvUNjBbyGUwCUFyBDvdcdIzaChOO0bEi5JVZRxNhRIQVsyOvUEat6gFROdcoh95HhoUS-Mac5cLzJFt12vSx_E7m_VUIfI",
               "width" : 398
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJbdIhoLNqkFQRMTiHCN6W4nU",
         "rating" : 4.4,
         "reference" : "CoQBdwAAAN3wdCAgdfatcILheBD3VwNP0Z_Zqjq8niNljnqpzHYJ2ieG6VEgxvfMQCU8BfawcRxO7MTu08gXtElThcYPdrQy5KFfAgdj1dFqi8PUh5R7wKKChjGN-sPj2cqRSIR-K853WjMlNMAhZSJMc2XWAhlbmy2AbXoe_9LsPoQfYE72EhCOBHIK_E0gTGPetycfRP6MGhSlBGpKKlZL00qldn6Xd44Y1TDj7A",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1427 3rd Ave, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.606546,
               "lng" : -122.335449
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "3f23cf0c8bfdbe746a69d518c031dcafbd266d64",
         "name" : "Netzel Associates",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ1Q6vb7FqkFQR0PCOSJtLQpM",
         "reference" : "CoQBdAAAABiMSr5ILBmkVjTeRpVAVHij7jMxhTacAJvz9YTFXVQYCP8he5wD4pAfaOu5dBlI4oagjaPPq8qUif9_hYN_IHTKpYnHaFWqCoHsHe-6kKIO1sIiE5qdLG-Buz2tQkVIPmzPqk67X60dgRux31vZjf10dg6BvizIiMTk5Q8D4AZWEhCJKbWcknUroTKKyatmH0JwGhS2i7O8iONEf9A5_qTBl3N1K8v4fg",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1111 3rd Ave # 2500, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.612607,
               "lng" : -122.336984
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
         "id" : "1672b9dd46c6dcb5ae1409d0f87b23f1c38f33d0",
         "name" : "Market Fresh Winter Garden",
         "place_id" : "ChIJrdhDMksVkFQR0ugNKk-w7Fk",
         "reference" : "CoQBfAAAAAxvLHmqlrTabI8g1bBkEMySU_pDqmYpmKmWNie37kRzknuKxRQkbPiVOs7cCB4yxiJGZ2X79qQW1dTFpJ9EE4jclrSKMFqzDqzPET1VHCR_imCSIWRLz_51iveURUW8r2GszBwCDISlu1iB1GBuLT58UB8Ghs-N3_yGxqaE_1JAEhBJn_a6kPPhJqGq9_pr4AifGhQNEEknt7JSyB1mvXCDgZ4o83aNng",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "meal_takeaway",
            "restaurant",
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "509 Olive Way, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.613069,
               "lng" : -122.329411
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "08e8916d1ade44b3403b1a1268fc038bd449952b",
         "name" : "Pike Grocery",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 384,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAmx9YeUnwUAcOesWmlueyy2ZJQT-GLpRSd0_WXWHV0pP7c42-FvQYcfkpRoDPCHiqlzJSWa_fPcqADGvAi_HaLFCcUhcIbbrTeJOSvlP1bA_ACdWmPBDF26vYc6xAJqmtR37EXiZ5j-sVYh09_hpEzRIQap8C87zKuwIYfsR6zsAg2RoUsAbkV4FLlFmsKTthHEbVdd0G9VM",
               "width" : 512
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJMwdemspqkFQRUqQ91N-ufeo",
         "reference" : "CnRvAAAAPclUek8vRV5Wcsbp4G08nttAphmKfTASUhTAR4I8vUnTFkSp7NP06JC4y3Xj7qTr9I105d7HpVkQJhuH6HDyLzej-FM5yDc7LqNMmkrAN3CcmQezcd9MhSZkdXdTDKTsYaZV4GgWogi4lqFcUgfhDBIQd1M7Sq4-EWJ4Y6cNUJPKHBoUnHoVxfWyl3lK7imAxJkxGkKNH9k",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1011 Pike St, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.606521,
               "lng" : -122.337704
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "110c00b34dc635662716772ab4a0e0f6deced28a",
         "name" : "Young's Market",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ44qIiLFqkFQRw1TsXz9H2kg",
         "reference" : "CnRwAAAAxMdsj6FXUIP8S9c42j9nSu7XtMyNY612TS6njqubsoZLBJwpr6GmxsrRKREPttLtBSYWOmq4gP2ovwO2utvqtLpjHcWs2YCFhNKj4k8Sz7F_d3aoAzOwNKmIp88bPxMbPUJj9eKI5gvTxct9CfRe4BIQolTWxCAybHKlUTMnfVgNfhoUlO1jmn7wrjUBVBcnZYe5QubTl_w",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1210 1st Ave, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.608777,
               "lng" : -122.33973
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "d2f9218e208a84da7c7a7e2980cebd3671a8f386",
         "name" : "Double Dorjee",
         "place_id" : "ChIJkX3s-LJqkFQRQRexqCN0jQY",
         "reference" : "CnRvAAAAoRDVxZ8W_qmEWPmjxXulAz9lS562rRQgirkEIhgXesLoXNgcJsw2iQIymEUKRmvQwrAOuLYrOIa8t1yPQdYYAvEajqIxcZ0PWzMEUeaDuCKL37p_WGzKOJuHhv0ki_3Z10BOPwmCNvo5XiOfz7j1ABIQK9UdmY_KTIYTP8tnoG5T_RoULYEoZrNBYy8EULQD7LUGs_E7krU",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1501 Pike St, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.608248,
               "lng" : -122.339523
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "efeff82fc657a72cf8a3079aabe0e27d0d91a6c5",
         "name" : "Lina's Fruit & Produce",
         "place_id" : "ChIJD22J-LJqkFQRxhEAGumCphs",
         "reference" : "CoQBeAAAAFcDpYes7w9SDBBHP_bOYNQrM1CUQichslNR-hyXATeyWMptKnIEdS27q0HR5BLfQAzQvgP_yIM2ElDrfSjtSdTVgiJlWZuVhtsBRIdV4n8cthl6uihZJnmtevrBYRq7GEid2Bp_IZiLJ4K6nYIpsyKlJNpBBvcKASbEsn4TAtM-EhCYsE2fgYPwEgX4ZHAkU6t7GhS2-N0cGpHzmVMAgNMKYP2GCW23-g",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1431 1st Ave # 7, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.605109,
               "lng" : -122.333955
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "d81b188da1c901ec10149c5224e6fd1beac9ef9c",
         "name" : "Second Avenue Sundries",
         "place_id" : "ChIJexG9_rBqkFQRi7Zb8KM4P98",
         "reference" : "CoQBeQAAAOH07x4jtyj3WTa6sWNSHXCPGItPL7kbSJbQFreF2VUJ-vxjenChmIoGcvsIREYEsV_dZYyXG3RoMpezUCUkuIvLsaEt1wxJcK6t0tM8QHylTdcc9IJRmjE_npy9rTbIehBixa5ESV1EGmF_rhyHQJyhPjAz7hmDcdlysEBRuySsEhAq3UlVuENA0aC8L59q8ZEFGhSUrFU9dmUkkl24SQ6RMQvA74mB5w",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "999 3rd Ave, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.614062,
               "lng" : -122.335451
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "69ff94699431b37223bdea4fd7792c7244a6b36c",
         "name" : "Sphere Foods",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ1ef53EoVkFQRlYzOwPY7DhA",
         "reference" : "CnRuAAAA6qjCWZS9h_Eb5x5UOAN2J99LIsJ9NEVR-LtbjUoLKx5OJmLmGGYEazQmbf02Rp8TrqyEVeE41rHimDGdvnQkj5WbLrxQCVM195Y3bLssymy7kUTFVaiclgZjVdEPf5WLcC9Xl6JjfiWxqN-5I1oEihIQZtGMYRH317G1c7rRQWd9MxoUmSFfTX5FwgECzfDH7hRFX4F5mJA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1700 7th Ave # 2100, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.614425,
               "lng" : -122.334307
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "e5be7cde6eb52cb0a5a7aa975ea915e2f80bd7dc",
         "name" : "Stewart Street Market",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1152,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAqeZQn6gaLGIJib2WaNAcw7GdNLJuCc6AvrMCF543GBpl9tgLJ99CS0DmrdbHyWVMcw_H7q_LZgOqqKLwkilB95SjXsJqu4O3KMVQQAqtQWHW27u2vKVkTOqxAWTDppdManOPMUlFP2LLN1zya33z2xIQY-si5NTVqW9CpTd2AhP9NxoURwp9wSSgmZY2dtC1q6OezNsUvQw",
               "width" : 2048
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ7yBfx0oVkFQRcLjVXNF_3qg",
         "reference" : "CoQBeAAAADTkEpb503o9qN93lxGtIlh8x-uyIgRIs0Pj_-gGXpxQoQkAnIGcmVYgDLEzcFtpgzDchjxRWmns1RPUhqnThNJp4_VmG3ZP42zFNDAO_Q2_YowPiM7Wgz3oQsr66uIEBKZnNW9QRrd_GMbA64OdLZGrn7wZwvdp5UWCCnJJe0NFEhBKdwGNlHZTu2Y4BOi6Zl-lGhSbbDS4npeTaLx_cwgpmTmKUpp43g",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "convenience_store",
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "1812 8th Ave, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.609322,
               "lng" : -122.325655
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "87b467979468e6d2b5b203c7486d84e08505dd17",
         "name" : "Plaza Select Foods",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 720,
               "html_attributions" : [ "From a Google User" ],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAhzdJBafPaRrh7mLSuB87bVza6ErJKRSvyNKU6pGa1EcblihzmqNx67HZQog-EO7wkvag7KP0bNXWvNXo9RF5u2vYNxZZ-5v7Z7KhL7tOmfWi7U7n6aFr9Sls_fZ_KcpBmH-m63Nl4H6E5GDFZwwNuxIQJUHOGAtXDDa9YT62KVkEjhoUVenpQc8oBGHYJOwTPiJDxSf2aH8",
               "width" : 960
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJy1bFH7ZqkFQRXpKoZ2NFh2Y",
         "reference" : "CoQBdAAAAJZ0WNOu_ProGJ7t62FbE2ADOx6sGGH0YIR1KNGRqiZ9scWKjBjMhUHb3VNKZzEuvFUIBPOjrfBtkbjpEUthCC8HHbe_hsuLCyp2FUi2AFDVgBWB49X4fPla0IcNoOECfEzwRskswcKgcNyob1wt_mB2nEEbQVFDr8W6vhRsl1EyEhBgAGQ9WXQzLHZzzRs84JEyGhRM0Rx5TiF0g11uFT5mg6v6uHr97g",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1024 Madison St, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.608802,
               "lng" : -122.340552
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "14a2e0601f06734e7c8be82ed00d3806e3f9ecd4",
         "name" : "Corner Produce",
         "place_id" : "ChIJn9FR9rJqkFQR89xobVdunBE",
         "reference" : "CnRwAAAAFad6cCCAww55VmSDqvH9XCZzHx5LoyFH2MHT5YkFM9NZNr7L3eKhd02_VnSEunZ3sMlCyvT37k-Tg6EZV4MuWVOZ2imbVrPX1OeRgJWS6OgXx-FHabcAj2W5jgRkCsHwEhjwTW0DNYNDX5GEn-a1HRIQNsCEN53Q1PC3NAHCTutgARoU-4Qq8ZOFJfF3Lyyc1Xf66FN8KQ0",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1500 Pike Pl, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.60884,
               "lng" : -122.340616
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "2a7a890254bcb2b1ae409cbf78d4e741800f036f",
         "name" : "Oriental Mart",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 460,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://plus.google.com/115115924044576716973\"\u003eMatt Good\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRtAAAAYab-XNz1Tm-iiB1qfxZJiC-T--LI7Mr5haR62p-RlGTrAIAPk2lhWogWOTQcFjPIHCiM2aYN2Iu-qkqPVGsEGony955zdEo6T3oOUKgNvT5WZvw6w_WU3aNdyLNh0xh-wRi4TNi6T70jutWPs6qkrRIQbdKBlQ6Yk1ROLxYnfSYF0BoUn9chrbaMj73dJleIqEzjxmi-9nY",
               "width" : 816
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJt7FX9rJqkFQR-R2iORwxyXQ",
         "reference" : "CnRvAAAA8b_D2XlfYEVl6Oi5uYGRdJILg6dW3oRrLu8Q9xd9EukH2omaTGNlupKgahjJREN5jiNKdj9FSmpR4F0Du2XMbW9xmMEpO6CmPEG8zbBHQVNBs2zHzU2_m0WFnLv21mdxfAd20GVX6f6cdZ2COkb_KhIQhh6kZ-vny430yF0EvmH7eBoUZ3TVjq_RHxXlY_jpaN1qk2Yc3UM",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "convenience_store",
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "vicinity" : "1506 Pike Pl #509, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.608918,
               "lng" : -122.340729
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "301d23a6579067833036e39ef46357e1d8e5ba68",
         "name" : "Frank's Quality Produce",
         "place_id" : "ChIJpdHb8LJqkFQRo8X7RoXoz2U",
         "reference" : "CoQBeQAAAKEBHFRM9OPUb4CWC5bC1HYamXOFc0lzWyWCX-4eyhtOOIEvcxHIsj4y1xkBiXTIsttPetJYNr5KKux3Y3q5ZF7SKutTqiRYbk0hESohet1_EdcnPU31_IBRLo9W-T_7wiDb3FnN24rYmz9J9Kz7pxhlyKyR2VLMuTLMALNLJC2YEhChDDy463zp0HRiZaAsFSG3GhTe1n0deejJDnxNB2AK4zOf1HGkMw",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1508 Pike Pl, Seattle"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 47.609231,
               "lng" : -122.340848
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "228c792a04f0d9c3b8086b9f857521945f87c975",
         "name" : "Choice Produce",
         "place_id" : "ChIJmbBY97JqkFQR4JkuKXVDT3A",
         "reference" : "CnRwAAAAWE1aK6eOe-rdRjgs2HJZHB__viCdWu2u7Qx0chME1CgDnnOycW_dcim98Szb2bzUjTy12wGk9fGO42jpywL-Zevm_ilfqi6q7jvRQxSGvsybbZau_Tc_orGj41Gz8fWK1R6_YvAT1n0II9DPFca1lxIQviRIxzWL3GRqyK3dun_4zRoUrNDpGHpGZHKUngGPiBLLH46zOqI",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "1514 Pike Pl, Seattle"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I need to parse it and get the lat and long values

I have assigned it like this

```
JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json= null;
```

Where result contains the web service response. How can I parse it and get the required values?

Comment: The response is a JSON object, not an array. That's why the `new JSONArray(result)` will fail.

Comment: JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(result);
   JSONObject json= null;      
   lat = new String[JA.length()];
   longde = new String[JA.length()];
   
   for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
   {
    json=JA.getJSONObject(i);
    lat[i] = json.getString("lat"); 
    londe[i] = json.getString("lng"); 
   }

Comment: Ok How can fix it and get thse (lat,lng) as pairs in an array??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the response to JsonObject like this

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);// where result is the response you got
```

Get the result array like this

```
JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results"); // where results is the tag in resposne
```

Now you have the entire array in results
for loop the entire stuff

```
    for(int i=0;i<results.length();i++)
    {
       JSONObject location = results.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");;
       String lat  = location.optString("lat");
       String lng  = location.optString("lng");
    }
```

If you need the lat and long inside an array, add those to an array.

Answer (score 2):

try this code.you will get lat and lng value:

```
 if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject geo = c.getJSONObject("geomatrics");

                    JSONObject place = geo.getJSONObject("location");


                    String id = place.getString(lat);
                    String name = place.getString(lng);
                   }}}
```

Comment: let me know,if your get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the response JSON is an Object, not an Array.

### Steps to get lat/lng values:

1. Get `results` JSON array from received JSON Object response
2. Iterate through all the sub JSON Objects, then first get `geometry` sub object.
3. From geometry sub object, get location object. From location object, parse and get lat/lng values.

Please don't ask for code as there are many JSON tutorials exist on web but you can use below methods for parsing:

1. getJSONObject()
2. getString()
3. getLong()

Comment: can you write it here?? I am new to this buddy.

Comment: @androidsuckzzz you can refer blog post written by me [Android JSON Parsing tutorial](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/).

Comment: code will be help full dear friend, I am new to this

Comment: @androidsuckzzz my dear code is already given in that tutorial. I can't donate blood directly, you have to eat and digest something!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple locations in the JSON so you will need and `ArrayList` to store all of them.

I recomment using `ArrayList<HashMap<String,Double>>`

Assuming you have the result as a `String` object named as `result`:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Double>>();
JSONObject jsonObj= new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
for(int i=0;i<results.length();i++){
    JSONObject temp = results.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location");
    Double lat = temp.getDouble("lat");
    Double lng = temp.getDouble("lng");
    HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    map.put("lat",lat);
    map.put("lng",lng);
    list.add(map);
}
```

now you can retrive any position by using

```
Double lat=list.get(4).get("lat");
Double lng=list.get(4).get("lng");
```

Hope it helps. cheers :)